# set display performance for document

Tags: adobe-indesign, basil.js

If I set my display performance and run a basil.js script then basil seems to override my display performance settings.

What I would like at the end of the script is set the display performance settings to fast display.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck as app.displayPerformancePreferences seems to be readonly 
(ViewDisplaySettings.HIGH_QUALITY, ViewDisplaySettings.TYPICAL or ViewDisplaySettings.OPTIMIZED). See http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Application.html and search for "displayPerformancePreferences".

Comment: The object itself (in its entirety) is read-only, but the performance preference *can* be changed: http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_DisplayPerformancePreference.html